# How do I display a success message after redirecting the user back to my home page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a registration form that uses AJAX and PHP for validation, and I can currently display error messages on the registration page if the user does not correctly fill out the form. When the user successfully registers, he or she is taken back to the home page of my website via:

```
echo
    "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        window.location.href='../index.php';                     
    </script>";
exit();
```

I want to know how to display a success message at the top of my website once this occurs, preferably a message that disappears if the user refreshes the home page after the message has already been displayed.

Comment: This is called `flash message`. I googled and found [this](https://mikeeverhart.net/php-flash-messages/index.php) library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sessions so it doesn't show again when you refresh the page.

Serverside:

```
$_SESSION['success'] = 'Registered!';
echo
    "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        window.location.href='../index.php';                     
    </script>";
exit();
```

Homepage:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['success']) && ! empty($_SESSION['success'])) {
    echo htmlentities($_SESSION['success']);
    unset($_SESSION['success']);
}
```

Make sure you initialise sessions with `session_start();` before trying to manipulate them

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in couple ways but the easiest one is to pass an argument to the index.php file

```
index.php?status=1
```

and then in the index file, you will check if that argument exists and what value does it have (for example 0 - error, 1 - success)

```
if(isset($_GET['status'])) {
  if($_GET['status'] == 1) {
    echo "User was registered successfully!";
  }
}
```

or you can define (on the script that verifies user data and login) a session variable with a success message and display it on the index page

```
   if(isset($_SESSION['success'])) {
     echo $_SESSION['success'];   
   }
```

Reminder: Don't forget to call the `session_start()` function on both pages (index page and in the validation script)

Answer (score 0):

That is specific to your app, but what I would do is after successful login set a message in a PHP session then check for that session on page load of index.php